# android:implement timer task

Tags: android, timertask

I am making an app in which i have to send gps coordinated after 1 hour if the app is open and one time when app is opened after logging out means when the app starts the gps coordinated will be send to server and if the app remained opened for 1 hour , gps coordinates will be send and if the app gets closed before 1 hour , the app will not send gps coordinates.My code is as follows:

```
TimerTask timer_task = new TimerTask() {

            public void run()
            {
                        Log.v(".............................................", "Timer Task Started");
                        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@ timer task started  IN TRACKER11111");
                        try
                        {
                            // if (locn != null)
                            {

                                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
                                String time = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
                                String xml = xml parameters being send to server
                                System.out.println(xml);
                                System.out.println("hello");

                                System.out.println("Xml is : "+xml);

                            //  FileSave obj9=new FileSave();
                            //  obj9.Save(xml);


                                int len = xml.length();

                                byte[] data = xml.getBytes();
                                System.out.println("Length =****************************  " + len);

                                System.out.println("Stream Closed");

                                conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                                if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
                                {
                                    //if (gps.equals("yes"))
                                    {
                                        new Connection(data);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                }

                            }
                            }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timer_task, 4000, 3600000);   






         }
        catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: where are you stuck??You can use AysnTask or Service depending on your needs.

Comment: Vincent, i am using timer task and when i logout from my app still the task works in backgroud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the given code accordingly:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timer_task, 0, 3600000);
```

and set the time and mininum distance in location manager which is as follows:

```
mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,3600000, 40,  mlocListener);
```

where 3600000 is the time slot and 40is distance in metres and mloc manager and mloc listener are location manager and location listener